# Remote Desktop hang OS or block all the connections

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04.02 fresh install, where I need to access through VNC or Remote Desktop(XRDP). 
I can access using putty without problems, I install XRDP using this [article](https://medium.com/@vivekteega/how-to-setup-an-xrdp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-89f7e205bd4e), I am using XFCE4 as GUI.

I can access to my remote ubuntu server from windows pc and after a couple of minutes the session is closed and I can´t access to the remote server, even using Putty I can´t access and is required a hardware reset.

Any advice in how to troubleshoot this issue or someone have the same issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a known issue with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and xrdp.  xorgxrdp package does not get installed when using xrdp packages from official Ubuntu repositories.  This is because a new package (xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04) has been introduced and which is not supported by xorgxrdp package

To fix your issue, the easiest would be to use the "unofficial xrdp packages" compilied against this new xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 package...  To use these "unofficial packages", you can issue the following commands

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martinx/xrdp-hwe-18.04 -y
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install xrdp

More information about the issue can be found at  http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390

Hope this help 
Till next time 
See ya